# Excel VBA UDF Add-in function #Name error

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF I wrote and put in an add-in.  I put it there (with a library of others) so that I can change functions and just deploy an updated add-in, thereby eliminating the need to modify hundreds of workbooks which invoke the subs/functions should I need to change them.  This is all being done in Office 2007.

It had worked well until recently when users started moving to Windows 7.  Now, only on Windows 7 (XP is still okay) there are #Name errors in cells.  This occurs under specific conditions (only a problem for Scenario D below).  In short, I have two workbooks each invoking, let’s call it, “FunctionX”, so let’s say cell A1 of each has “=FunctionX(parmA, parmB)”:

Scenairo A – If I open either workbook separately  (All is well)

Scenario B—I open both workbooks at the same time  (All is well)

Scenario C—I open both workbooks separately, one after the other, in different instances  (All is well)

Scenario D—I open one workbook, then the second, in the same instance of excel (#Name errors in cells of first workbook invoking FunctionX)

I realize the work-around is to only operate via Scenarios A-C, however I keep getting users complaining about D.  If they go into any invocation of FunctionX on the #Name offending cells and hit enter, the #Names go away, but a programmatic forced recalculate does not do this (my initial attempt at a band-aid).  Is my only recourse to write a procedure that loops through all open workbooks, goes into a cell with my function forcing a code-driven enactment of what the user is doing, or am I missing something?
Thanks…any/all advice appreciated.

Comment: Are ALL UDFs affected or just one?  If it is just one, what is special about it?  Can you post the code for it?

Comment: All UDFs...I just used one for example/explanation.

Comment: Have you checked add-in security settings?

Comment: The security settings are no different that those set-up for the same set of operations in XP (or the other listed scenarios) which work.  This is strictly in Windows 7 when two different workbooks are opened in succession, both using UDFs from an add-in.

Comment: My guess is that this might be related to Excel storing the full pathname of the file where the UDF is defined. When the 2nd instance of the same function becomes available, it might be making the first definition invalid and marking it not found (#name). I would try moving the UDF to a separate, true add-in that is loaded independently of the data files. Also, not sure how Windows 7 is related, unless: its really a difference in office versions or the new systems are storing the excel files in a different location than in XP (that involves sharing, auto updating or versioning?).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What do you mean separate true add-in (mine is an excel .xlam which is loaded independently via application add-in, and then referenced within each of the workbooks)?  Also regarding OS, I can't imagine why it would cause this either, but it does.  :)

Comment: By the way...one more bit of complexity I didn't realize was relevant (though apparently is, as I tried it without and did not encounter the #Name issue).  The UDF in the add-in calls a function in a DLL which is referenced in the add-in.  
Again, works fine for scenarios A-D on XP, but only A-C on W7.

Comment: Sorry, I interrepted your abcd scenerios with workbooks as having the udf code self contained in each workbook. So, we're in agreement about using one single xlam as the udf source. Odd about the dll - there were some common control dlls that havent been distributed in Office 2007 that were common enough to exist from other apps in XP (like the windows calendar control). But missing the DLL would cause the vba to fail completely. Unless the dll versions installed on the two OS's are different - with it failing on the win7 version.

Comment: The DLL is one I built and installed (the install differing by machine only for 32 versus 64 bit).  But since it does work for the other scenarios on that machine, it doesn't really fail completely...just when opened subsequently as in "D".  Thanks again for responding.

Comment: Are the version of Excel also different? XP 32 with Excel 2007 32 and Win7 64 with Excel 2007 64? Do both versions of the DLL (32/64) have separate GUID's? Each bitness would live in different registries, but wondering how the reference to the DLL in the UDF gets resolved when files are reloaded.

Comment: You know, when I look on the user's machine...the Excel 2007 application is in their Program x84 folder, however the process tag says while in an instance reads EXCEL.32.  The DLL does have a different GUID, so you are right about the DLL living in a "different registry" so to speak.  I guess I may have to let this one go, but I just can't figure out why it's capable of finding the function via ID one way (namely all other scenarios), but not the other.

Comment: Actually, I just looked and the GUIDs are identical between the 32 and 64 bit machines...just a different install package.

Comment: Sorry, for Excel 2007, there is only a 32bit (I had to do some similar dll load problems with Excel 2010 for both 32 and 64 bit versions). So, yes, it should be in the x86 directory. And since Excel is only a 32 bit version, it will only look at the 32bit DLL. Your 64bit dll install shouldn't be used. I don't think that in itself would cause the #name problems, but maybe some other assumption about what is getting installed is broken?

Comment: The important thing with a UDF (whatever it's in an add-in or a workbook) is to define it inside a **module** otherwise you get the #NAME error. But you said it used to work in Excel previous version, so you had it in a module, and I don't see why you have this error in the context you describe.